# Как ограничить ширину адаптивного owl слайдера на больших экранах?

Tags: html, jquery, css, вёрстка, slider

Всем привет! Вопрос по owl карусельке: на больших экранах свыше 1370 мне нужно ограничить слайдер шириной до 1510 пикселей. просто добавление ширины id="owl-example" max-width равной 1510px ничего не дает, т.к. ширина адаптивной карусели высчитывается относительно экрана. Как это можно правильно сделать?

```js
 $("#owl-example").owlCarousel({
   items: 4,
   itemsDesktop: [1369, 3],
   itemsDesktopSmall: [1099, 2],
   itemsTablet: [768, 2],
   itemsTabletSmall: [739, 1],
   itemsMobile: [479, 1],
   pagination: false,
   navigation: true,
   navigationText: ["", ""],
   autoPlay: true
 });
```

```css
.owl-item img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.owl-prev {
  background: url('../../images/prev.png') no-repeat!important;
  width: 29px;
  height: 55px;
}
.owl-next {
  background: url('../../images/next.png') no-repeat!important;
  width: 29px;
  height: 55px;
}
.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons div {
  position: absolute;
}
.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons .owl-prev {
  left: -45px;
  top: 44%;
}
.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons .owl-next {
  right: -45px;
  top: 44%;
}
#owl-example {
  width: 99%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="carousel">
  <h3>ПОПУЛЯРНЫЕ БУКЕТЫ</h3>
  <div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel">
    <div>
      <? u_img(21); ?>
    </div>
    <div>
      <? u_img(22); ?>
    </div>
    <div>
      <? u_img(23); ?>
    </div>
    <div>
      <? u_img(24); ?>
    </div>
    <div>
      <? u_img(25); ?>
    </div>
    <div>
      <? u_img(26); ?>
    </div>
    <div>
      <? u_img(27); ?>
    </div>
    <div>
      <? u_img(28); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: если пишу так, то картинки обрезаются 
#carousel {
  width: 1345px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
если задаю картинкам max-width, то они потом динамически переопределяются

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы шли в верном направлении. Для блока id="owl-example" можно присыоить max-width: 1510px, но только в настройках карусели указать

```
responsiveBaseWidth: '#owl-example'
```

т.е. в вашем примере это будет выглядеть так

```
$("#owl-example").owlCarousel({
      items: 4,
      itemsDesktop: [1369, 3],
      itemsDesktopSmall: [1099, 2],
      itemsTablet: [768, 2],
      itemsTabletSmall: [739, 1],
      itemsMobile: [479, 1],
      pagination: false,
      navigation: true,
      navigationText: ["", ""],
      autoPlay: true,
      responsiveBaseWidth: '#owl-example'
    });
```

Тогда каруселька будет вычислять ширину не по ширине окна браузера, а по ширине указанного блока.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте использовать `@media`:

```
@media (min-width: 1370px) {
 #owl-example {
      width: 1510px;
    }
}
```

Comment: фигня получается - слайдер просто смещается влево